# database architecture for ecommerce app

Tags: database-design, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I’m creating an app that allows `users` to post, sell, and purchase `items`. Every `item` has a `count` integer attribute that is set by the initial `user` and which is reduced by n with each purchase. When `count` is 0, that `item` can no longer be sold unless one of the previous `user` buyers reposts the `item` they purchased: in which case, the new `item` inherits all the properties of the original `item` except for `price`, which is determined by the new `user` owner, and `count`, which is determined by how much `count` they purchased in the initial transaction.

I have two database columns at the moment - `items` and `users`. I’ll need to record transactions and ownership transfers for as long as an `item` exists on the site, so this means that I'll need a third column for `transactions`. What else would I need, and what else should I research? Is Standard Table Inheritance useful for this kind of functionality?

Should I scrap the whole `count` approach? Would it be a huge drag on the database if I created one new object for each `[i]` in `count`? So say a `user` sets `count` to 10,000 and I had the app create that many individual database objects for every `item` posted. And then say there are thousands of people doing the same thing at the same time with their own `items`.

Very new to working with database design and not sure where else to ask, so I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Are your users selling/buying real-world items (stuff that is useful outside your website), or it is some kind of market within a game?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau they're buying and selling real-world items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty typical inventory management problem.

How you manage it depends on how you physically manage inventory.  If each item (not SKU, but item) has a unique serial number, then you may be tracking specific item instances.

More likely, you'll get a box of the item (widgets, say) and increment the inventory on hand by the count in the box, maybe 24.  Each sale transaction decrements the inventory on hand by the number sold.

My rule is: keep it simple, but keep it real.  If your have multiple warehouses in different timezones, or that kind of thing, you have a more complicated problem.  If you have a single warehouse, then life is easier -- just add `num_on_hand` or similar to the `item` entity.  (Don't use `count` since that's a SQL keyword, amongst other reasons).

This is a good case in RoR for a transaction; make the decrementing of `num_on_hand` part of the `add to cart` or `checkout` transaction.  Don't forget things like adjustments (e.g. end of year inventory), breakage, returns, and all the other things that are transactions but may or may not actually change inventory.

I would also hasten to point out that this is a problem that has been solved countless times, and is just one of many issues around content management, store management, etc.  Is this software you really want to write yourself, or is there a nice existing gem or tool that you can use to manage this complex problem more simply so that your company can get to the problem of doing what it's good at, like, selling stuff :-)